# Having buttons inside the modal box

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I added a previous/next button on my modal. However, the position of the button will go crazy if I zoom in/out the window size. I know that it is not a responsive design, but is there a way to put the button inside the modal box, just next to the content (between the margin of the box and the image) for this time? No matter how we zoom in or zoom out the window size.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
function bit() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

//Image Control
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 40%;
}


.mySlides {display: none}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: gray;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}



/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<meta name="google-site-verification" content="m5WU4qQAgnH-cFn0MhAZFzuvfnDKktYgRaxpGukwh7M" />
<?php echo $header; ?>

<div class="container">


<body onload='javascript:bit()'> 



<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->

  <div class="modal-content" style="width:740px">
    <span class="close">close&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><br>
<div class="mySlides" align="center"><img src="/image/catalog/banners/Sale.jpg" width="700" height="560"></div>

<div class="mySlides" align="center"><img src="/image/catalog/banners/New_Year_Sale.png" width="700" height="560"></div>

  </div>

<div class="slideshow-container">
  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: have `position:relative` as parent div and buttons with `position:absolute` inside that parent div.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got that.